# Spring-Boot + Velocity generate exception at startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently testing using Spring-Boot to deploy a Freemarker application.
I fact my simple test is working fine. But in my log I see the following exception and I wonder what it could be:

```
2014-08-14 15:03:26.774 +0000 DEBUG         [                main]    [o.s.w.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer:346] -  Cannot resolve template loader path [classpath:/templates/] to [java.io.File]: using SpringTemplateLoader as fallback  
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar!/templates/
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:207) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

But my templates are correctly used. Is that exception "normal"?
Note that we are not using the Spring-Boot parent pom. We are using our own parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a DEBUG log. I should think that makes it ignorable.

Answer (score 0):

you must create a /templates folder in your /src/main/resources/ and it must contains velocity files or you can skip auto config with exclude in @EnableAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration below would solve the problem!

`spring.velocity.prefer-file-system-access=false
spring.velocity.prefix=/templates`